# Trying to build a gallery, how to fade out currently displayed div and fade in the next one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a new personal portfolio site using very basic html/css/jquery code. I'm trying to build my own gallery to display my work (instead of using an already existing one like lightbox) but I've run into an annoying issue: I've tried to make the "forward-button" display the immediate following div but instead it fades in all the following divs. Here's my (condensed) code:

HTML:

```
<!--navigation buttons for gallery-->
        <a id="back-button"><img src="image.png" /></a>
        <a id="forward-button"><img src="image.png"/></a> 

        <!--gallery begins here-->
        <div id="gallery">

            <div id="first-div" class="work-display">
                <img src="images/albumust-display.png" class="work-image" />
                <div class="caption" id="wd1c">
                    <p class="caption-text">caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="second-div" class="work-display">
                <img src="images/ce-display.png" class="work-image" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="caption-text">caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="third-div" class="work-display">
                <img src="images/display.png" class="work-image" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="caption-text">caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS (all divs inside gallery are hidden by default):

```
    .work-display {
      display:none;
      position:absolute;
  }
```

What I'm trying to do with Jquery is that everytime someone opens a thumbnail, give the corresponding div that displays the image on full size a "true" state of "active" and then fade in, like this:

```
$( "#thumb-1" ).click(function(){
        $( "#first-div" ).prop("active",true);
        $( "#first-div" ).fadeIn();
    });
```

all divs originally have a state of "active" = false:

```
$( "#gallery" ).children("div").prop("active",false);
```

then this is what I've tried to do with the "forward-button":

```
$("#forward-button").click(function () {
        $("#gallery").find( $("div").prop("active",true) )
        .prop("active",false)
        .fadeOut()
        .next().fadeIn();

        $(".caption").fadeIn();
    });
```

But then what it does is that instead of fading in only the next div, it fades all the divs that come after. what am I doing wrong?

I'm very new to Javascript/Jquery so probably this isn't the smartest way to go about this, if you have a simpler solution, do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't test it properly, because I don't have the whole code (and the images either). But this should do the trick:

```
$(function () {    
    $("#gallery div").attr("active", false);

    $("#thumb-1").click(function () {
        $("#first-div").attr("active", true).fadeIn();
    });

    $("#forward-button").click(function () {
        $("#gallery div[active=true]:first")
            .attr("active", false)
            .fadeOut()
            .next()
            .attr("active", true)
            .fadeIn();
    });

    $("#back-button").click(function () {
        $("#gallery div[active=true]:first")
            .attr("active", false)
            .fadeOut()
            .prev()
            .attr("active", true)
            .fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Kind of demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W8VLh/13/

Comment: Give this answer a try and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have a reason to use 'active' properties instead of classes:

```
$("#forward-button").click(function () {
    $("#gallery").find( "div[active='true']")
    .prop("active",false)
    .fadeOut()
    .next().fadeIn().prop("active",true);

    $(".caption").fadeIn();
});
```